# In Kotlin, how can I choose which textview a button should show the text?

Tags: android, kotlin, textview

I have two textviews in Kotlin, say Textview No 1 and Textview No. 2.
I want buttons to show their text in one of the textviews that I select. E.g. Button "A" to show the text A in the first textview when I click the textview No. 1, and Button "B" to show the text B in the textview No. 2.
It is similar to a calculator, just that calculators have only one textview. I am interested to show only the text, not mathematical calculations.

Thank you

Comment: Depends in which variable you store the `TextView`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val textViewA: TextView? = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewA)
        val textViewB: TextView? = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewB)
        val buttonA: Button? = view.findViewById(R.id.buttonA)
        val buttonB: Button? = view.findViewById(R.id.buttonB)

        buttonA?.setOnClickListener {
            textViewA?.text = buttonA.text
        }
        buttonB?.setOnClickListener {
            textViewB?.text = buttonB.text
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way.

What are the events you are handling?
Event 1: Click of button 1
Event 2: Click of button 2

on click of Event 1 what do you want to do -> choose which textview to show the text -> use an AlertDialog to select between the two textviews and depending on that show the text.

Comment: Thank you. 
Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I want to have two buttons and two textviews: Button A and Button B and tV1 and tV2. I want to be able to choose which textviews will showthe text of my buttons, e.g. when I click on tv1 to show button A or B, and tv2 to show button A or B text. My point is that I want to choose which tV to show the text of my buttons.  
Thanks again

Comment: You need to have an intermediate action to choose.. I think using an alert dialogue to choose between the textviews is an option . SO you click the button an alert dialog pops up asking you to choose and then show the text depending on the choice . Here's the documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog